# How do I find out what IP and Port a Net::HTTP request is bound to?

Tags: ruby, net-http, tcpsocket

I am writing an application for generating network traffic and I would like to include the ip address and port number of the requestor.  Can I get this information from Net::HTTP or is there another library I can use that has this information.  I just need to be able to make http requests and handle the response object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is easy enough if I use TCPSocket instead of Net::HTTP

```
TCPSocket.open("www.google.com", 80) {|sock|
  sock.print "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
  sock.puts "\r\n"

  sock.close_write
  puts "ADDR: #{sock.addr}"
  puts "Peer: #{sock.peeraddr}"
  @response =  sock.read
}
```

sock.addr and sock.peeraddr give me the addresses I'm looking for.  Unfortunately, now I don't know how to cleanly get the status code (200 - OK, 404 - Not Found, etc)